# Is my answer politically incorrect or what?

Tags: discussion

["Terrorism has no religion." Why don't Moderate Muslims restrain their Radical counterparts?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/9292/terrorism-has-no-religion-why-dont-moderate-muslims-restrain-their-radical-c/24864?noredirect=1#comment87438_24864)

There are several possible answers actually.

1. Majority in islamic countries are not as influential as much as majority in democratic countries
2. Lack of freedom of speech
3. Majority of muslims may be somewhat sympathetic to the terror groups.
4. Religions are tools of lying and tend to benefit those in upper class. Hence, terrorism, that tend to benefit politicians become a popular interpretation.

All of those answers are deleted or censored.

I think people should at least give reasonable argument why I was wrong. It's as if people in the west think that islam is "just like buddhism" and somehow wants to justify that terrorism has nothing to do with islam.

Of course it has. You don't see buddhist blow themselves up and scream dharma is great.

Not now.

And I give reasonable answers. The muslims are different.

I think I give a very reasonable answers based on my experience living in a country with muslim majority. They are indeed different and those differences explain why we got islamic terrorists.

I tried to answer 3 times each of which using completely different angles. All are deleted. Are there any reason why people think my answer is wrong?

Comment: What's the point of posting multiple very similar answers to the same question? Your original answer was not removed, and you were advised to update it instead of continuously posting new answers.

Comment: You got positive points out of what I read as a rant; you pretty much claim religion is a lie and religious leaders are generally corrupt without any citation. I think you got off lucky and I blame the Hot Network Questions.

Comment: My answers are deleted. The new one has a different angle. Rather than changing the old one I just create another answer.

Comment: My first answer revolves around 3. My last answer revolves around point 4. That's 2 totally different answers.

Comment: @yannis all of my answer is removed. That is the problem. If it's not removed I would have change it.

Comment: Have you been following events in Myanmar?

Answer (score 4):

The goal of SE Is to provide THE correct answer to a question.  This is not a forum where you can try out different posts to see if any get good traction.  The posts all seem to address the same point, in fairly similar logical fashion.  None of them are fact based instead relying on opinion, even those linked pieces were opinion based articles.  None of which provide quality material for an answer.

Had the answers been substantially different(I know its subjective, but thats why we have human mods instead of programmed processes) I suspect they may not have been deleted.

Anything that shows your personal bias as transparently as yours does, be it left or right, gets tons of downvotes(though admittedly more for the right). If I cared to I could write your answer in a more factual less opinion based way that would not attract nearly as much ire and would not get deleted. I have no desire to do so.

Comment: I got a feeling that anything that don't follow the liberal theory that islam is just "misunderstood" religion that's used by "evil" people to get what they want will be removed. Those liberal don't see that there are enough muslims that support jailing people that says exactly that

Comment: May be not majority but enough to make the person actually go to jail.

Comment: Anything that shows your personal bias as transparently as yours does be it left or right gets tons of down votes(though admittedly more for the right).  If I cared to I could write your answer in a more factual less opinionbased way that would not attract nearly as much ire and would not get deleted.

Comment: By the way your argument suffers from an appeal to popularity fallacy

Comment: Dude, if you can turn that answer into a good answer, please so. Best governor in Indonesia is jailed because of islam. I have no idea whether it's what Islam truly is, or whether it's just evil people using islam. One thing for sure is I never heard any jewish governor sent to jail for protesting people lying with religion.

Comment: @J.Chang I did that above....

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basuki_Tjahaja_Purnama you can read more about it. A governor being supported by 43% voters and have 77% approval rating is sent to jail because of islam. Not even the majority of muslims want him sent to jail. But that's enough

Comment: Okay cool @SoylentGray. I am just concerned with people prohibiting freedom of speech and wanting an effective governor sent to jail.

Comment: You have the right to say it.  That does not give you the right to force me to read it, or allow it on my social media site.(not claiming ownership of SE just defining rights)  You are free to create your own social media site to promote your agenda

Comment: I never claim that right. You're right though. I'll find others. This one is very bias toward liberals.

Comment: Let's put it this way, if Islam is just like Christianity, why do you think Ahok is sent to jail? What is it in Islam that makes people want to send someone to jail for his speech? And is there a connection between that and terrorism?

Comment: @J.Chang - I have no desire to address the content issues with your post beyond the reasons for the answers being deleted, and your remaining answer not being well received.

Answer (score -2):

I took the time to go through your three answers.

1. They are poorly sourced, as was pointed out in a comment.

It might have been okay if you stated unambiguous and unchallenged facts. It is not in this case.

Example of ambiguity:

> *"about 20% (of muslims) support terrorism"*.

By which poll/study ? Which terrorist group do they support ? It is not unthinkable that they have a stronger support when polling about the hezbollah than for boko haram for instance. You cannot just pull this out of thin air.

[A few links that might help you](https://www.thereligionofpeace.com/pages/articles/opinion-polls.aspx#terror). If you use these, be accurate. [This one for instance](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/1510866/Poll-reveals-40pc-of-Muslims-want-sharia-law-in-UK.html) states an understanding of the "feelings and motivations" of the 7/7 attackers from 20% of british muslims, but a disapproval of the act by 99% of them. You can for instance use this to support that there is not enough counter-terrorism speech in some places. Not that 20% of british muslims are potential terrorists.

Example of challenged fact:

> *"about 20% (of muslims) support terrorism"*

Let us assume you are right. This fact will be challenged in:

- muslim theocracies who need the favors of western countries for some reasons, and don't want to be viewed as ennemies (military aid, sanctions lifting, ...)
- muslim majority authocracies fearing an uprise of some islamic group (this case can be merged with the previous one)
- muslim minority countries, including most of the west, where for instance organisations against extra vetting of muslims will probably tune it down, while those in favor of extra vetting of muslims will probably tune the percentage up.

This leaves very little places with a non-emotional view on the matter. Hence the need of a study to support it.

It is not like if you stated *the USSR was leading the communist block during the cold war and*...

Example of plainly wrong fact. Here is a passage from a source you quoted (extensively)

> it is everyday Muslims who discriminate against, persecute, enslave, rape and murder Christians almost every day in Pakistan.

Apart from the drama or rethoric (see 2.), you picked this from a forum with very little peer review. Which explains the erronerous facts. The majority of pakistani muslims does not take part in the enslaving of pakistani christians. Apart from the errors, this also poorly informed, there are a few places in the muslim world where slavery is still practiced, although illegal (Sinai, Mauritania, Libya, ISIS-controlled places, ...).

Picking such a source just makes us less likely to believe anything you write.

2. Another element from your answers that have no place on Stackexchange, the drama. Here is a sample from one of your answers :

> What would you do to change the politic in your country?
>
> Terror.
>
> Of course.

I am not judging the quality of the rethoric, but rethoric does not have any place here.

Comment: So, basically, you dislike the answer not because it's not supported but because (due to argument from incredulity) you don't like specific assertions it makes that violate your personal view of the world (since you're just fine with unsupported assertions that don't violate your personal view like a guess about oil prices). **Either you need support for both assertions, or for neither**.

Comment: (and yes, there's plenty of polls showing high support for terr0rism as a tactic - NOT specific groups - among wide variety of Muslim populations. Specific 20% number probably came from  ICM Poll showing [20% of British Muslims sympathize with 7/7 bombers](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/1510866/Poll-reveals-40pc-of-Muslims-want-sharia-law-in-UK.html)). There's plenty more polls like that, some far worse.

Comment: @user4012 It is not about dislike, the answer was deleted way before I got a look at it. It is about methodology, especially in troubled waters. With a link like your, the answer might have been more accepted. I am sure it is possible to find worse polls, especially in muslim countries, the point is to find one appropriate to the question.

Comment: @user4012 Yes, I don't think established and well-known facts need to be justified. For instance, answers don't link to some lesson about the cold war each time the topic is brought up.

Comment: and that's the problem. you absolutely arbitrarely claim that the fact taht you don't like isn't "established and well-known" whereas something that isn't actually all that well known (oil prices) is. As far as many people are concerned, the fact that a large majority of Muslim populations hold this belief is most certainly "established and well-known".

Comment: @user4012 The oil price example is from a high school program, I will change if you don't think it is general knownledge. And I was actually well aware of the "fact I don't like", which is how I know not everyone knows it, and lots of people distort it one way or the other. Including you, I searched (https://www.thereligionofpeace.com/pages/articles/opinion-polls.aspx#terror ), the majority is not that clear. Which is why a study is needed.